# Is it possible to print one letter of a string at a time on the same line?

Tags: vb.net

I was wondering if it was possible to type a string out one character at a time (so it looks like it's being typed out).

Thanks for any replies!

Will

Comment: Could you please tell me how?

Comment: Since you thanked the person answering with a VB.Net answer, I have removed the VBA tag. For future reference, they are not the same language and you should not tag your questions with both.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an answer that works. If you want to create a typewriter effect that makes it seem like someone is typing, here you go.

```
Dim stringer As String = "test, lol!"
Dim printstr As String

For Each c As Char In stringer
    Console.Write(printstr & c)
    printstr = printstr & c
    Threading.Thread.Sleep(150)
Next
```

Oh yeah, and if you find a function that waits and keeps the application fairly responsive, use that instead of

> Threading.Thread.Sleep(150)

Answer (score 0):

You just need to loop all the characters of the string, print them one by one and set a little delay.

```
    Dim str As String = "a string out"

    For Each c As Char In str
        Console.Write(c)
        Threading.Thread.Sleep(150)
    Next
```

Comment: @FatPoo2 Proper "thanks" on SO is to click the checkmark.  It not only removes the question from the Unanswered list, it shows you actually participate in the process here.